# Pictorial "riddle" v2

Tags: riddle, visual, rebus

L00k at the 0rdered images bel0w and determine the phrase that they c0llectively represent:

[image: enter image descripti0n here]

Hint: It's a "place"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be:

> Charlottesville

The images are:

> **Charles** the Great
>  2 parking **lots**
>  Cruella de **Vil**